# swift compiler warning をターミナルで一覧表示する方法はありますか？

Tags: swift, ios

Xcodeではプロジェクト内の`swift compiler warning`が一覧ででるのですが、
ターミナルで一覧として出したいです。grep等したいためです。

Answer (score 1):

`/Users/[ユーザー名]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/プロジェクト名-ランダムな文字列（重複を防ぐため）/Logs/Build`

フォルダーに作成される、

`.xcactivitylog`ファイルがコンパイルログファイルになりますので、日付が一番新しいものを参照すれば良いと思います。

他にも

```
xcodebuild -project プロジェクト名.xcodeproj -target ターゲット名 -configuration (Debug|Release)
```

と、ターミナルからビルドを実行することで、コンパイル結果をターミナルに出力することも出来ます。(`Debug`|`Release`)はどちらか一つを選択というつもりで書きました。
この場合は、Bash系を例にすると

```
xcodebuild -project プロジェクト名.xcodeproj -target ターゲット名 -configuration (Debug|Release) > compile.log 2> error.log
```

の様に標準出力と標準エラー出力を分けて、ログに書き出すのが良いと思います。